# How to do a sharing field for mutiple people?

Tags: php, ajax, html, sharing

Similar to Facebook, I want to do a sharing feature where a user can choose to keep something private or share with 1 or more people.  I know how to do a drop down but that limits my ability to be able to do it only for one person.  How do i do it so i can allow people to select more than 1 person in a way that its user friendly and not confusing.

I was thinking of using AJAX or if HTML5 had something but i am new to that area so i don't know.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I only tried doing the traditional drop down that allows you to select one option.  I haven't progressed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `<select multiple>`, but that's not very user-friendly. I'd use something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple.

Comment: Thats perfect! Thanks.  But in the var availableTags they have their own values.  I will be using PHP to get the names of the people. How do i do that in this script then?

Comment: I suggest you read the whole docs for the jQueryUI autocomplete, it allows you to fetch the options from PHP using Ajax.

Comment: jQuery UI is not usefriendly if javascript is not available.

Comment: The regular select multiple can be used as a fallback when js is not available.